# Doctrine2 Batch processing

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to import text file with 10000+ lines into DB. I've found a manual [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/batch-processing.html). But my script ends just before reaching the final `flush` without any error. The boolean parameter in my custom flush method stands for calling `clear` method after flushing.

Code:

```
$handle = fopen($file, 'r');
    if ($handle != FALSE) {

        // Clear entities
        $clear = 1;
        // Read line
        while (($data = fgets($handle)) !== FALSE) {

            $entity = $this->_createEntity($data);
            echo $clear . '<br>';
            $this->getPresenter()->getService('mapService')->persist($entity);                
            if ($clear % 100 == 0) {
                echo 'saving...<br>';
                $this->getPresenter()->getService('mapService')->flush(TRUE); // Flush and clear
            }
            $clear++;
        }
        echo 'end...'; // Script ends before reaching this line
        $this->getPresenter()->getService('mapService')->flush(); // Final flush
        echo '...ed';
    }
    fclose($handle);
```

Custom Flush method:

```
public function flush($clear = FALSE) {
    $this->db->flush();
    if ($clear) {
        $this->db->clear();
    }
}
```

Echo output:

```
1
...
9998
9999
10000
saving...
```

But no `end......ed`.

Thanks a lot in advance.

**EDIT**

I've changed number of line in files to process in one batch from 10k to 5000. It's OK now. But I still wonder why 10k is "too much" for PHP or Doctrine.

Comment: quite likely some error is happening, would it be useful to use a 'try.. catch' around the while loop?

Comment: @RyanVincent, thanks for response. I did that before before posting. No error was thrown and catch.

Comment: Maybe you have to detach entities which you have flushed. `EntityManager::clear()`. Doctrine entities eat up a lot of RAM.

Comment: @DanFromGermany, after 100 flushed records "clear" method is called.

Comment: @PeterO. `flush` does not detach entities, it just clears the `UnitOfWork`.

Comment: @DanFromGermany, please check my question above - I've added "Custom Flush method" code. Called in `$this->getPresenter()->getService('mapService')->flush(TRUE)`

Comment: @PeterO. aaah ok I see, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try using feof:

```
$handle = fopen($file, 'r');
if ($handle != FALSE) {

    // Clear entities
    $clear = 1;
    // Read line
    //while (($data = fgets($handle)) !== FALSE) {
    while (!feof($handle)){ 
        $data = fgets($handle); 

        $entity = $this->_createEntity($data);
        echo $clear . '<br>';
        $this->getPresenter()->getService('mapService')->persist($entity);                
        if ($clear % 100 == 0) {
            echo 'saving...<br>';
            $this->getPresenter()->getService('mapService')->flush(TRUE); // Flush and clear
        }
        $clear++;
    }
    echo 'end...'; // Script ends before reaching this line
    $this->getPresenter()->getService('mapService')->flush(); // Final flush
    echo '...ed';
}
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried it but nothing has changed. It might not recognize end of the file but records look OK.